# Spring Cloud Task Launcher doesn't respond to new events sent to Rabbit

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to setup a very basic Spring Cloud Task example but I'm having a problem with the Task Launcher not receiving the events (I think).

Using the most basic sample to send events:

```
@RestController
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@SpringBootApplication
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Application {

  private final Source source;

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @RequestMapping(path = "/task", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void sendRequest() {

    final TaskLaunchRequest request =
        new TaskLaunchRequest(
            "maven://org.springframework.cloud.task.app:timestamp-task:jar:1.0.1.RELEASE",
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);

    final GenericMessage<TaskLaunchRequest> genericMessage = new GenericMessage<>(request);

    this.source.output().send(genericMessage);
  }
}
```

I can confirm this does send the `TaskLunchRequest` to Rabbit as expected.

However using an equally simple example on the other end yields no results

```
@EnableTaskLauncher
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

And the dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-task'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-deployer-local:1.3.7.RELEASE'
```

I was expecting the `@EnableTaskLauncher` to go ahead and start a new jar based on the maven url passed in.

Note the `application.properties` for both projects are empty. I've not defined any channels or anything as none of the sample applications I've looked at have anything specific set either.

Is there anything further I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work this out from a large number of blog posts and GitHub samples.

Looks like out the box the `TaskLauncher` is listening on `input` and I was obviously sending messages out via `output`.

A solution is to define both channels in your configuration as such

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output:
          destination: task-launcher
```

And on the other side

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: task-launcher
```

Note the difference between output and input.